# Is openCV good for production codes?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project which uses openCV to extract SIFT features from image and also uses some ML of opennCV. This project is to be deployed in production. Is openCV good to use for production codes? Will its dependencies cause issues? If so what are my other options?

Comment: SIFT is patented, that's why it should be in the NONFREE module of opencv!

Comment: Does this mean that I can't use SIFT for code in a commercial product?

Comment: I dont know how to get a license, try contacting the patent holder.

Comment: @Bhaskar - You would need to talk to [David Lowe](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/home.html) and get a license before using it in any of your products.  TBH, I was considering using SIFT for the stuff I'm using, but the amount he wanted per unit of the product we were manufacturing was highway robbery.  As such,  I'm using OpenCV's [ORB detector](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html) for what I'm developing, which IMHO performs just as well as SIFT/SURF.... and it's free!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "production code" you mean "commercial product": the SIFT and SURF algorithms are patented and are not to be used commercially.  That's why they were moved to the `nonfree` module. ([source](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/nonfree.html))

Comment: For anyone reading this today, SIFT patent is now expired and you may use it. However nowadays it may make more sense to use deep learning for feature extraction.